# Does Spring @Qualifier expect bean ID as an element value? Is Spring @Qualifier's element bean ID behind the scenes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Does `@Qualifier("identifier")`'s [element value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html#value--) specify a candidate bean's ID for a fine-grained selection, or it specifies something else (alias, for example)?

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html#value--) of `@Qualifier` does not really say much of this or of anything else with respect to relation of its element to candidate bean ID.. but, there is some interesting behaviour:

If I have several `@Component` classes implementing one `interface A`, and:

1. If I define one of those components with custom ID, like `@Component("identifier")`, and if I will then try to inject bean with `identifier` ID somewhere else with `@Autowired @Qualifier("identifier")` - all works fine - which gives me an intuition, that the qualifying bean is *distinguished* from others and identified by its ID (I presume `@Component`'s value element is a bean ID, although [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) of @Component's **Optional Element Summary** is quite lacking);
2. If I, on the other hand, define same component with `@Component @Qualifier("identifier")` and the rest of the scenario is same - all would still work perfectly well.

**However!**, the interesting part what I have observed is that `@Component("identifier")` sets the respective bean's ID to `identifier` whereas `@Qualifier("identifier")` doesn't set the respective bean's ID to `identifier`.

If `@Qualifier` is something like an alias, what if the field to be injected has `@Qualifier("identifier")` for narrow criteria, but two candidate beans are available for injection, one with ID `identifier` and another with Qualifier `identifier`, which one will take precedence to get injected?

Anyone would shed some bright light on how all this works?

Comment: `@Qualifier` is a qualifier as a last resort it falls back to an `id` and `name` match of the bean. You can also create an annotation, which itself is annotated with `@Qualifier` and inject a bean annotated with that specialized `@Qualifier` annotation. See [the Spring Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) for a full section on the matter.

Comment: This gives even more confusion now. So, it relies/uses bean ID or/and bean name, which should be same as the current Spring version, right? I've read that name is just another type of ID with the possibility that you can enumerate and provide more than one name, whereas ID is always one and only. Creation of annotation is another topic.. my question lays in a bit different context here..

Comment: Your understanding is wrong and has nothing to do with the version. `@Qualifier` is a qualifier nothing more nothing less. If there is nothing to qualify it by it will use the `id` of the component.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong, as you just re-translate/phrase words which we can read as well. I know what the word qualifier stand for, context and the spirit of the question is way broader. Anyhow, thank you.

Comment: The question was if the qualifier is related to the id, and that is no it isn't. The id is only a fallback mechanism. That most people only use this fallback mechanism doesn't make a qualifier something of an alias as it is much broader then that. And thus a qualifier is that, to qualify something by something other the the name or id.

Comment: But when you have @Qualifier("someId"), it will inject the bean with ID someId, even if that bean's corresponding class doesn't have any @Qualifier annotation i.e. the bean has no qualifier.

Comment: Because it will use the id/name of the bean as a fallback mechanism... Check [the  implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java#L220) if you want to precise resolution mechanism.